# Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, less, head.js

I'm using LESS.js, Jquery, Respond.js, and Freetile.js.

I load them all using Head.JS (a first for me).

Could someone check out why I am getting this error? I've looked with Chrome developer tools, and all of the scripts seem to have loaded fine (I know this is usually an error with Jquery not being loaded, or Jquery being loaded after use).

I'm really banging my head against a wall on this one, so help would be greatly appreciated.

You can find the demo site I'm working on here: ----

Comment: have you tried to put $("#container").freetile(); on document ready?

Comment: the document ready did not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Access `$` after jQuery is loaded:

```
head.js(
     "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js",
     "assets/js/less.js",
     "assets/js/respond.min.js",
     "assets/js/jquery.freetile.min.js", function() {
    $('#container').freetile();
});
```

Actually the [head.js docs](http://headjs.com/) recommend this:

```
// use jQuery on the body of the page even though it is not included yet
head.ready(function() {
   $('#container').freetile();
});

// load jQuery whenever you wish bottom of the page
head.js("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js",
     "assets/js/less.js",
     "assets/js/respond.min.js",
     "assets/js/jquery.freetile.min.js");
```

Comment: this did it, thanks! Do i have to put all such calls inside those brackets when using head.js?

Comment: @user974703 The event handlers provided by head.js are the only place where you can be certain that scripts have been loaded, so yes.

Comment: For reference...since scripts like head.js work by adding script elements to the DOM, they can't do their thing til there's a DOM to add scripts to (read: til about the same time that jQuery's `ready` would fire).  Til that point, none of the script elements would have been loaded yet...and a script in the body would run basically as it's parsed, before the DOM is ready.

Comment: Thanks cHao, that really clears things up for me.